# A lot of : "error: no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::basic_ostream<char>' and '<unresolved overloaded function types>')

Tags: c++

This is the code :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "   SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS" >> endl;
    cout << " SS:::::::::::::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "S:::::SSSSSS::::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "S:::::S     SSSSSSS" >> endl;
    cout << "S:::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "S:::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "S::::SSSS" >> endl;
    cout << "  SS::::::SSSSS" >> endl;
    cout << "    SSS::::::::SS" >> endl;
    cout << "       SSSSSS::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "            S:::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "            S:::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "SSSSSSS     S:::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "S::::::SSSSSS:::::S" >> endl;
    cout << "S:::::::::::::::SS" >> endl;
    cout << " SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS" >> endl;
    cout << "IIIIIIIIII" >> endl;
    cout << "I::::::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "I::::::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "II::::::II" >> endl;
    cout << "  I::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "  I::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "  I::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "  I::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "  I::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "  I::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "  I::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "  I::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "II::::::II" >> endl;
    cout << "I::::::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "I::::::::I" >> endl;
    cout << "IIIIIIIIII" >>
}
```

This is for school so don't ask why I am writing this code. But i get a lot of errors like the one in the title and I can't seem to find the problem so if anyone can help me, it'll be great!

Comment: The insertion operator is `<<`, not `>>`. Also, you could have reduced the example down to a single line of code to demonstrate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When writing using the extraction or insertion operator (e.g `>>` or `<<` respectively) you need to basically point it where you want the flow to go, and not change the flow for that whole statement, to put it in simple terms, in your case you want both insertion/extraction operators that you use to be facing like so `<<` and that one is called an insertion operator.

This is the code you want:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "   SSSSSSSSSSSSSSS" << endl;
}
```

and replicate that for as many times as you want there to be output statements.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the flow going one direction and one direction only:

```
std::cout << "..." << std::endl;
```

You've got this going in and out at the same time.

You can't read from `std::cout`, it's for *output* only. It's an `ostream` which means it has no idea what `>>` even is. That operator isn't defined which is why you get that error.

Comment: Is it really necessary to answer this question, instead of commenting and voting to close as a typo?

Comment: @cigien It's not just a typo. It's an explanation of why that matters.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the error needs much of an explanation, but it's fine I guess.

Comment: @cigien Better than answering in the comments section.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I disagree. In general, yes, useful answers should be answers, not comments. But as far as the OP is concerned, they get helped either way. As far as the utility of this particular question is concerned, it's going to get deleted before the day is over, so what's the point?

Comment: @cigien There's sometimes a fine line between "answer as comment" and "answer which is basically a comment" and "answer which would be a tiny bit too much for a comment." I think people asking questions just want the answer, so the presentation is less relevant, but a brief comment and a close-hammer on your question does feel pretty cold.

Comment: Yes, I do see your point, and there are certainly many cases where an answer would be appropriate. There's nothing wrong with the answer, of course, but I just felt that in this case, it could have fit in a comment.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Those are all good questions, and I don't have clear answers to all of them. I do think my commenting and then closing, were correct actions to take here. Would you be interested in joining one of the chat rooms? There are some rooms devoted almost entirely to these topics.

Comment: @cigien No need; I've already passed on the facts. :)

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings You have indeed expressed your views quite clearly. As far as I am able, I have tried to do the same. However, it appears we still disagree on several issues. We have discussed this before several times, and it's probable we will do so again, and so I was rather hoping we could continue doing so in a forum designed for exactly that, instead of in comment threads spread out over multiple posts. I feel that you can articulate your views very well, and I would like to understand your POV better, and learn from that if I can.